# how to hide an apikey in a javascript request

Tags: javascript, api, api-key

for example , from the google maps api

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

now if I replace API_KEY with my key or even assign it to a variable which I use here , I can still see it in the page source . how do developers hide the apikey in requests ?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide it?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't!

Comment: bounce it through a proxy on the server side, but even that is only going to partially block it...

Comment: if you do not hide apikeys does it not risk letting other developers use your key

Comment: in many cases the API keys are restricted to to a domain or something along those lines by the key provider so its not much of a risk for general use

Comment: Create a web service or similar that calls google apis from the serverside, and call your webservice.

Comment: generally though API keys are meant to be the public half of the key and and server side validation on the key providers end with a private key or by domain is what makes the key work or not work